# Thunderbirds profili.ini is empty. How to rewrite it?

Tags: thunderbird, .profile

the title says it basically. My profile.ini from thunderbirbird is empty. I don't know why, but I would like to rewrite it to access my emails - can I somehow recover or rewrite it with some copy/paste example?

Edit: thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my working `profiles.ini`

```
[General]
StartWithLastProfile=1

[Profile0]
Name=default
IsRelative=1
Path=zs6nqxw4.default
Default=1
```

You will have to change the line with `Path=` to the correct profile, normally the profile is located in the same directory (`~/.thunderbird`). If you use a profile in a different folder, I guess you have to enter the full path to the profile you use.

You can edit your `profiles.ini`-file easily, you don't need sudo as the file is in your home-folder, just double-click  the file and it will be opened in your text-editor, then paste my example into the file and edit the line with `Path=`, save the file and you should be ready to go.